# LD+JSON Non-Scannable Email Address

Tags: javascript, json, html

I am scanning my website https://www.zachnewberry.com via site-analyzer and I am getting the following ding to my score **"Some email addresses have been found in the page. zach@zachnewberry.com"** I have identified the source of this problem its within the ld+json markup. Is it possible to link the following code thru external JavaScript or something of that nature to fix this?

```
<script type="application/ld+json"> {
"@context" : "http://schema.org",
"@type" : "RoofingContractor",
"address" : {
"@type": "PostalAddress",
"addressLocality": "Taylorville",
"addressRegion": "Illinois",
"postalCode": "62568",
"streetAddress": "412 W 1st St" },
"name":"Zach Newberry Construction",
"url":"https://www.zachnewberry.com",
"email":"zach@zachnewberry.com",
"telephone":"2178207597",
"image": "https://www.zachnewberry.com/images/card.jpg",
"pricerange": "$$$$",
"openingHours": [
"Mon-Sun 6:00-22:00"],
"aggregateRating":{
"@type":"AggregateRating",
"ratingValue":"5",
"reviewCount":"206"}
} </script>
```

Comment: Don't include your email in plain text! OR address, or phone number or any identifier for that matter.

Comment: then how do I pass the google markup test without plain text in the source?

Comment: Well first of all, you have to understand why. And that is because then bots will scrape your email and  you will be added to loads of spam lists etc. I posted that comment in reference to you including your details in the question. But google `obfuscate email javascript` and you should find your answer, or someone might post something here